# remove repeating pattern in a list

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list with repeating patterns. I want to remove these repeating pattern to make the list as short as possible. For example:

```
[a, b, a, b, a, b] => [a, b]
[a, b, c, a, b, c] => [a, b, c]
[a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d] => [a, b, c, d]
[a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c] => [a, b, c]
```

What is the best way to cover all the possible cases?

I have tried to convert the list to string, and apply regular expression on it:

```
input = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']

temp = ",".join(input) + ","

last_temp = ""

while temp != last_temp:
    last_temp = temp
    temp = re.sub(r'(.+?)\1+', r'\1', temp)
    print(temp)

deduped = temp[:-1]

output = deduped.split(',')
```

The function works well as expected result: `[a, b, c]`

However, there is one issue. If the input list is:

```
['hello', 'sell', 'hello', 'sell', 'hello', 'sell']
```

The result will be: `['helo', 'sel']`

You see, the regular expression also replaced the 'll' to 'l', which is not desired.

How can I fix this issue with my function, or is there any better way? Thanks

Comment: @enke, thanks for asking. Either way is fine to me.

Comment: @enke, Set may not work, for input [a, b, c, a], the desired output is [a, b, c, a]

Comment: Does this mean patterns like `aabc` are valid? Or `abac`? Can a pattern be an arbitrary length?

Comment: This task is not to remove duplications in a list. It is to remove a sequential pattern. For example, input: [a, b, a, c], output is also [a, b, a, c].

Comment: What about `abcbaxyxabcba`? Which part should be considered the pattern?

Comment: What do you mean by "sequential pattern"? How do you determine the sequence for `"hello", "sell"`? Why is it not `"sell", "hello"`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243627/discussion-between-lserlohn-and-ddejohn).

Comment: Maybe I should say, to remove "duplicated subsequence". There is no arbitary length for the subsequence. It can be any length.

Comment: "You see, the regular expression also replaced the 'll' to 'l', which is not desired." Do you really need to replace characters inside the strings in the list?

Comment: Rather than accumulating the result into a string and then `split()`ing it. Just build the list directly. This removes the need for a regex and the problem that you encountered with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sell` will be substituted by `sel` because `re.sub` substitutes the repeating character `l`.
You can tweak your regular expression to avoid matching those cases.
For example matching repeating patterns starting from the beginning of the string:

```
temp = re.sub(r'^(.+?)\1+', r'\1', temp)
```

Or ensuring the patterns ends with a comma :

```
temp = re.sub(r'(.+?,)\1+', r'\1', temp)
```

Edit: given your last example, it's probably best to check patterns between commas:

```
import re

list_in = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']

temp = "," + ",".join(list_in) + ","

last_temp = ""

while temp != last_temp:
    last_temp = temp
    temp = re.sub(r'(?<=,)(.+?,)\1+', r'\1', temp)
    print(temp)

deduped = temp[1:-1]

output = deduped.split(',')
```

A look-behind makes sure your pattern is preceded by a comma as well.

Answer (score 0):

I dont get why you would use regex in this case.
Why don't you use a "set" instead :

```
my_set=set(['hello', 'sell', 'hello', 'sell', 'hello', 'sell'])
print(my_set)

my_set=set(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
print(my_set)
```

Gives :

```
{'hello', 'sell'}
{'b', 'a', 'c'}
```

Comment: From the comments under the question: " for input [a, b, c, a], the desired output is [a, b, c, a]"

Comment: Please edit your question, it's not precise enough.